# Django template not found on production, but in dev is fine

Tags: django, cherokee

When I run the app in dev mode (./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9090) everything works fine. The template is rendered and everything is great. When I reload the production web server(cherokee) all I get is the Django template not found error.

I realize that this is a bit vague so feel free to let me know what info I need to share. I can't help but to think that I've got some simple mistake, but I can't find anyone with the same issue.

See http://signstreak.com/ for the error I'm referencing.

**EDIT**
This is literally the same code base. I'm very early on in development. I've so far been just creating the app using ssh+vim. So both dev and production is running the same code, on the same machine, at the same time.

I also just noticed that my DB settings are not getting imported. Strange. It is almost as if some random stock settings.py is being used.

Thanks,
-Kerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` variable is empty.

If you fix that, it will probably work again :)

Comment: It is literally the exact same code base. see http://50.19.120.245:9090/. So it would seem that somehow the settings.py file isn't being loaded or loaded correctly. I've never ran into this issue before.

Comment: @Kerry Hatcher: strangely enough... normally the `filesystem` template loader gives an error if you don't have any template dirs set. So that's already quite strange.

Comment: So I dropped Cherokee and feel back to apache and all is good now.